# Real Grassmann manifold and orthonormal groups

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, quotient-spaces, grassmannian

I'm trying to prove that the Grassmann manifold
$$G_k(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{E = {\rm {\it k} - dimensional\ subspace\ of\ } \mathbb{R}^n\}$$

is equivalent to:

$$G_k(\mathbb{R}^n) = \frac{O(n)}{O(k)\times O(n - k)}  \tag1$$

Where $O(n)$ is the orthonormal group of $n\times n$ matrices.

From my research I've seen that Eq. (1) is due to the idea of splitting the original $n$-dimensional subspace into a $k$-dimensional one and its orthonormal complement of $n - k$ dimension; but I don't get how this Grassmann manifold, which is made of vectors ($(k\times 1)$-dimensional matrices - column vectors), is related to $n\times n$ matrices since the quotient in Eq. (1) is the following set, as usual:

$$\frac{O(n)}{O(k)\times O(n - k)} = \{M_n\cdot (O(k)\times O(n - k))\ |\ M_n \in O(n)\}    \tag2$$

Can anyone explain me this relation and the prove of Eq. (1)? Thanks in advace! ;)

Comment: What is your definition of Grassmann manifold, i.e., in which sense is it made of "(1 \times k)-dimensional matrices"?

Comment: In any case, are you familiar with the characterization/construction of homogeneous spaces? See, e.g., Theorem 9.22 (Homogeneous Construction Space Theorem) in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

Comment: It is a vector space, isn't it? A $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $1\times k$ - matrices are vectors with $k$ components

Comment: I'm not familiar with that construction, but I'll follow your advice and I'll read it. Nevertheless, if you can show me how to get Eq. (1), it would be really greatful. It isn't neccesary that you explain the material that you suggest me to read in that book, I'll read it by my own

Comment: That description isn't quite right. The Grassmannian $G_k(V)$ is the space of all $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$. It is true that we can specify any such plane by giving a basis, i.e., $k$ linearly independent vectors in $V$, but that choice is not unique.

Comment: The question isn't quite a duplicate, but by chance I explained exactly this in an answer to another question a few days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2993101/155629

Comment: I've read the Theorem in Lee's book and its chapters about manifolds and group but I don't find the solution to my question. I don't get the relation given by Eq. (1), i.e., matrices-vectors. What I think I've found is that the little group of $O(n)$ is $O(k)\times O(n - k)$ and I know that for some Lie group $G$ with little group $G_p$ and $p \in M$ ($M$ the manifold in which $G$ acts) we have that $G/G_p \simeq M$. So Eq. (1) should have (continue...)

Comment: (cont.) $\simeq$ symbol instead of $=$. However, the proof of $O(k)\times O(n - k)$ being the little group is something that I don't see clearly. Actually you don't give it in the other post. Do you suggest me any reference for it?

Comment: Since $O(n)$ acts transitively on the space of $k$-planes, we can identify $G_k(\Bbb R^n) \cong O(n) / H$, where $H$ is the stabilizer of a chosen plane. Taking the plane spanned by the first $k$ basis vectors, any element in $H$ must have the form $\pmatrix{\ast&\ast\\0&\ast}$. Now, use the fact that such elements are in $O(n)$, so that $A^T A = I$, and conclude that the elements of $H$ are those in $O(n)$ of the form $\pmatrix{B&0\\0&C}$ (all of this is in the linked post). Along the way (or just substituting afterward) you'll see that $B^{\top} B = I$ and $C^{\top} C = I$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the [*Steifel manifold*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold) of $k$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$ S_k(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{(v_1, \ldots, v_k) \mid \text{the $v_i$ are orthonormal} \}$$
The group $O(n)$ acts transitively on $S_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by acting on each vector: $g \cdot (v_1, \ldots, v_k) = (gv_1, \ldots, gv_k)$. The stabiliser of a frame $(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ will be the subgroup of $O(n)$ which fixes the span of $(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ and acts nontrivially on its orthogonal complement. This subgroup is isomorphic to $O(n - k)$, and hence we have
$$ S_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \cong O(n) / O(n - k)$$
Next, there is a natural map $\phi: S_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by taking the span of the frame. The fibre of this map over a point $E \in G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ will be the set of $k$-frames spanning $E$, which is a set isomorphic to $O(k)$ (an isomorphism of $O(k)$-sets). Hence $$G_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \cong S_k(\mathbb{R}^n) / O(k)$$
These together give the equality you were after.

Comment: i don't get the last paragraph. Why do you talk about fibres and divide by $O(k)$?

Comment: @Vicky: For $E \in G_k(\mathbb{R^n}$, its preimage $\phi^{-1}(E)$ is the set of $k$-frames in $E$. This set is isomorphic to $O(k)$, since $O(k)$ acts freely and transitively on it. This means that $S_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ looks like $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with some copy of $O(k)$ glued to each point, so $S_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \cong O(k) \times G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as sets.